# Правку поправили после моей проверки

Tags: поддержка, предлагаемые-правки

Я тут отклонил [правку, в которой перепечатали код с картинки с кучей ошибок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/225584). Однако сейчас я захожу в эту проверку — а перпечатки кода уже нет! Правку в том виде, в котором она принята сейчас, я бы и сам принял.

Это нормально, что автор правки может изменить её до принятия (как я понял, здесь именно это)? Это нормально, что при этом моё отклонение не превратилось в тыкву? А то как-то неловко получается: сейчас выглядит так, будто я отклонил правку по выдуманной причине. Может, с этим стоит что-то сделать?

Comment: Очень странно. Я такого ни разу не видел раньше. Так как данных, подтверждающих Ваши слова просто нет. Как будто Вы действительно отклонили полезную правку. Может какие-то гонки?

Comment: Во [временной шкале](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/766264/timeline) что-то не очень понятное.

Comment: @alexolut, похоже, автор правки внёс дополнительные изменения поверх исходных, уложившись в пятиминутный *период свежей правки*. Подобная деятельность, вроде, не создаёт нового элемента в очереди на проверку.

Comment: Но это неточно, потому и не публикую ответом.

Comment: @Arhad автор правки не имеет репутации для таких действий. Или Вы о том, что **предлагаемая** правка может быть изменена несколько раз за 5 минут и в очереди фигурировать в разных редакциях? Если так, то это явно баг.

Comment: Как я понял это работает так: пока  правка не будет утверждена пользователь может менять содержимое правки. По сути это логично потому что мало ли найдется дополнительная ошибка нуждающаяся в исправлении и надо заново делать утверждение( т.е. много спама в проверке).